# There is or There are

Tags: grammar

Kourtney Kardashian said "there's people that are dying Kim" in one of the KUWTK episodes- why did she use there is instead of there are?

Answer (score 2):

Informal spoken English is often not strictly correct or does not follow the standard conventions of written English. "There are people" would be correct.